# Android x86 Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, tethering, android-x86

I have installed Android x86 7.1 r2 and Remix OS last update installed. My WiFi adapter does not work. But my android USB tethering sometimes works on android x86 only when connected before boot.

Found a imperfect solution. Android x86 ifconfig detects connection as `eth0` but does not initialize its preference like IP address or mask. I have to reset all network from settings to initialize the `eth0`. Can anyone perfect it?